# Create sum of ones till N using macro in Rust

Tags: rust, macros, rust-macros

I would like to create a macro for transforming `count!(5)` into `1+1+1+1+1`.
The final reason is to use `count!(N) - 1` into a structure definition where `N` is a const generics.

```rust
macro_rules! count {
    (1) => {0};
    (2) => { 1 + count!(1)};
    ($n: tt) => { 1 + count!($n - 1)};
}

struct WindowIterator<I, Item, const N: usize> {
    iter: I,
    values: Box<[Item; count!(N) - 1 ]>,
    index: usize,
}
```

With this definition, I receive an error like `no rules expected the token` N .

How can I change my code for making it correct?

Comment: Your plan will not work since macros are expanded *before* any type deduction or template instantiation; that and macros only work via tokens, not values. However, I'm puzzled by the idea in the first place since your code compiles using `N` directly: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=de997c1d1f41ab892f040795380878e5).

Comment: It seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: updated the questions. I need to create an array with length N-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, it's not possible with current **stable** Rust. Current Rust support for const generics is MVP, and const generics with complex expressions are not supported in stable build.

However, it's possible with Rust nightly build.

```rust
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

struct WindowIterator<I, Item, const N: usize>
where
    [Item; N - 1]: Sized,
{
    iter: I,
    values: Box<[Item; N - 1]>,
    index: usize,
}
```

[Rust Playground link of the example above](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5a95ea5e31b814bf87081b905392f8bc)

You can check out further details in this [official Rust blog post about const generics](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/02/26/const-generics-mvp-beta.html#const-generics-with-complex-expressions).

Comment: updated the questions. I need to create an array with length N-1

Answer (score 0):

Macro expansion works on raw tokens. If you follow the macro expansion process...

```rust
#![feature(log_syntax)]

macro_rules! count {
    (1) => {{
        log_syntax!(MatchOne count!(1));
        0
    }};
    (2) => {{
        log_syntax!(MatchTwo count!(2));
        0
    }};
    ($n:tt) => {{
        log_syntax!(MatchNumber count!($n));
        1 + count!($n - 1)
    }};
    ($($n:tt)*) => {{
        log_syntax!(MatchAny count!($($n)*));
    }};
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=89c8ccc21658752cfbdcdd02e31c44a7).

Outputs:

```
MatchNumber count! (5)
MatchAny count! (5 - 1)
```

The second invocation didn't get `4`, but `5 - 1`, the raw tokens.

What you want can be done with procedural macros, for example:

```rust
extern crate proc_macro;

use itertools::Itertools; // When std's intersperse() will be stable, can get rid of this.
use proc_macro::{Delimiter, Group, Literal, Punct, Spacing, TokenStream, TokenTree};

#[proc_macro]
pub fn count(number: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let number = number.to_string().parse().expect("expected a number"); // A simple way to parse int literal without `syn`
    let result = if number == 0 {
        TokenTree::Literal(Literal::u64_unsuffixed(0))
    } else {
        TokenTree::Group(Group::new(
            Delimiter::None,
            std::iter::repeat(TokenTree::Literal(Literal::u64_unsuffixed(1)))
                .take(number)
                .intersperse(TokenTree::Punct(Punct::new('+', Spacing::Alone)))
                .collect(),
        ))
    };
    result.into()
}
```

However, this is probably not what you want.